# Is it possible to replace the default search application in Windows?

Tags: windows, search, hotkeys

When I press Win+F I get the Windows search window. I want to replace that with a different search application, is it possible to re-map the Win+F shortcut to a different application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created a AutoHotkey script to run FileSeek on Win+F. Works fine.

Comment: This seems to be the best option right now. :)

Comment: That's at: http://www.fileseek.ca/

Answer (score 0):

Not directly what you're looking for, but if you install Google Desktop, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> brings up the search box. And you can then disable the native search.